# sp_executesql : Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    'select * from AccessOrganizationSettings where OrganizationSys = @OrganizationSys', 
    N'@OrganizationSys nvarchar(250)', 
    @OrganizationSys = '805408'
```

But I get this error:

> Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'select ...', ..., @OrganizationSys = N'805408';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you need `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`. Try:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    N'select * from AccessOrganizationSettings where OrganizationSys = @OrganizationSys', 
    N'@OrganizationSys nvarchar(250)', 
    @OrganizationSys = N'805408'
```

The `N` makes the string an `nvarchar` datatype.

Comment: ah ok!  It took me a few seconds of staring at your answer to see the difference between my query and yours.  I was missing the first N.  (I will mark as answer as soon as it lets me)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston *ALL* the `N`s are important, not just the first one. You should always include the `N` prefix for any `nvarchar` string literal.